# Observables and RG flow

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization, observables, effective-field-theory

I am confused about a standard thing regarding renormalization group eqn. The primary motivation of writing the RG eqns are observables do not depend on the UV cutoff $\Lambda$ (Wilsonian) or renormalization point $\mu$ (continuum). or $$\mu \frac{d\mathcal{O}}{d\mu}=0.$$

Now in the case of $$\mathcal{L}=\mathcal{L}_K-m_0^2\phi^2-\frac{g_0}{24}\phi^4$$ where $0$ are bare couplings, we renormalize the theory and can define the renormalized mass and couplings in some energy scale $\mu$. For instance, at some energy $\mu_0$ we define the amplitude $\mathcal{M}(\mu_0)=g_0$ and so on. Now is not these renormalized things are observables? Since we can measure these things experimentally. But these things do vary with $\mu$ which is not the definition of RG.

When we write the continuum RG eqn, we take $\mu\frac{d(m_0\text{or,}g_0)}{d\mu}=0$ and from there we get the $\beta(e)$ and $\gamma(m)$ functions. But the bare things are not observables. Any help is appreciated.